# How to Show Static text based on laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hello I'm working on a learning project by myself and facing a problem.

I want to show a list of users and at the right side I want show the user type like admin or user.

If the `Usertype` column has the value 1 then I want to show `Admin` and if the column value is 0 then I want to show `User`.
I am getting record from the Usertype column.

```
static public function GetUser()
{
    return self::select()
        ->get();
}

public function user_list()
{
    $data = user::GetUser();
    return view('admin.user_list', compact('data'));
}
```

Here is my HTML table

```
<table class="table table-bodered">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>User Role</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($data as $Udata)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $Udata->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $Udata->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $Udata->Phone }}</td>
        <td>{{ $Udata->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $Udata->Address }}</td>
        <td>{{ $Udata->Usertype }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

[image: Im getting data From Usertype column but I want to show text based on 0 or 1]

Comment: Use translations. Tip - use string like `admin`, not int.  https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's type.
     */
    protected function userTypeToDisplay(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn () => $this->Usertype == 1 ? 'Admin' : 'User',
        );
    }
}
```

Or the [old-fashioned way](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's type.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getuserTypeToDisplayAttribute()
    {
        return $this->Usertype == 1 ? 'Admin' : 'User';
    }
}
```

and in your view, you may use it as

```
<td>{{ $Udata->user_type_to_display }}</td>
```

Comment: Bad-bad-bad. Words in code very bad practice like magic numbers. Another language? New role?

Comment: @Maksim, _New role?_: add those to the config file. _Another language?_: use the role code from the translation file. But that's for another question. 

Comment: Nope. You answer to a newbie with bad practices. This is terrible. Question is "How to display user role in blade". Laravel good practice - localization.

Comment: @Maksim [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) ✌️ You are welcome to share an answer following the good practices, maybe both the OP and myself would learn from it.

Comment: *S*OLID - why do model know about how to display role name in interface?